# how does setTimeout work here

Tags: javascript, settimeout

```
function A() {
    // do somthing
    console.log("A");
    setTimeout(func1, 0);
    B();
}

function func1() {
    console.log("func1");
}

function B() {
    console.log("B");
    setTimeout(func2, 0);
    C();
}

function func2() {
    console.log("func2");
}

function C() {
    // do somthing
    console.log("C");
}
A();
// output: 
//  A
//  B
//  C
//  func1
// func2
```

But I change the func1 time to 1, func2 time to 2.The duration still last 1ms.But the output has changed.

```
function A() {
    // do somthing
    console.log("A");
    setTimeout(func1, 1);
    B();
}

function func1() {
    console.log("func1");
}

function B() {
    console.log("B");
    setTimeout(func2, 2);
    C();
}

function func2() {
    console.log("func2");
}

function C() {
    // do somthing
    console.log("C");
}
A();
// output: 
//  A
//  B
//  C
//  func2
// func1
```

Then I try with setTimeout(func1, 1001), setTimeout(func2, 1002).But the "func2" will still be output before "func1".It seems the setTimeout(func1, 0), setTimeout(func2, 1) is sepcial one.But The duration between two timer set up is always 1ms.And I want to figure out what makes output different.

Comment: can it be due to `do something` code snippet

Comment: There is no guarantee with the order of timer executions... http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Comment: @muraleekrishna there is nothing in "do something" here.

Comment: @Arun P Johny i am still not really clear about that.

Comment: In which browser? I tried Safari, Chrome and Firefox on Mac OS and the results are as for the first example in all of them. setInterval usually does not have a resolution of more than 3 or 4 ms (or perhaps a lot more in some browsers, IE used to be about 15 ms).

Comment: @ArunPJohny—that article is from early 2008, browsers have change a lot since then.

Comment: @RobG I tried it in Chrome.